# How do I access instance variables of parent model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, associations, parent-child

I have two models which are associated via has_many/belongs_to. I've created a class method within the child model. But I can't figure out how to access the instance methods of the parent model from within the class method. Here's a simplification of what I'm trying to do:

```
#User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses

    def first_name
        "John"
    end

    def last_name
        "Doe"
    end
end

#Address model
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    def self.full_name
        parent.first_name + " " + parent.last_name
        #returns full name of parent "John Doe"
    end
end
```

I'd like to be able to run this in the Rails console and have it return "John Doe"... but no luck. Any suggestions?

```
@user = User.first
@user.addresses.full_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@user.addresses.full_name
```

This returns an array so you need to pick a single object from the array, assuming the array is not empty.

```
@user.address.first.full_name
```

What does this accomplish? Because you can get the full name off of the user object and it shouldn't change based on address :(

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses

    def first_name
        "John"
    end

    def last_name
        "Doe"
    end

    def full_name
        self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
    end 
end
```

So now you can access `full_name` from the `@user` object

```
@user.full_name
```

Comment: Right, I know I can define the full_name within the User model itself. What I'm trying to do is figure out how to access parent methods from within a child.

Comment: I simplified the problem to User/Address model to make it easier to respond to. My real problem involves a User model and an Activity model. The Activity model is backed by an external soap resource. I am trying to make a method where I can call user.activities.refresh to fetch the SOAP resource by accessing the user_id in user.user_id. I'd like to be able to do this if the activities array is empty.

Comment: if you want to access parent methods from within the child you already know the parent so just call the method on the parent. I'm obviously confused and don't get what you want :)

Comment: Apologies for my of lack clarity, I'd like to make a URL "http://www.mysite.com/users/1/activities/refresh" to fetch data from a SOAP resource and save it to the activities table. I defined class methods for consuming/saving the SOAP response in the Activity model.Those methods need to know the parent's user_id. So that was why I was trying to access the instance method of the parent model... I think perhaps it might be simpler to just have the controller pass the user_id, so that I can refresh by calling user.activities.refresh(user_id)?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing class inheritence with Model relationships, and class methods with instance methods.

Lose the "self." in "def self.full_name" - it's not doing what you think. Then replace "parent" with "user." Parent is giving you a reference to ActiveRecord::Base, which has nothing to do with the relationships you've defined. "user" will give you that particular address's User object, which is probably what you're looking for.

The previous answer has already gone into why you can't call "full_name" on @user.addresses.

Comment: Thanks, this helps explains why parent wasn't working since it refers to ActiveRecord::Base. However, I'm still wondering how I can refer to User instance methods if I define a class method within Address. For example, if I have an instance of a user as @user, and I want to call @user.addresses.fetch_from_soap to fetch addresses for a user named "John Doe" from an external SOAP source? How might I do this?

Comment: Wait, if you're grabbing the addresses from a SOAP source with fetch_from_soap, why are you calling @user.addresses too? Calling @user.addresses will query your database for addresses where user_id=@user.id and return an array of matching Address objects. Are you storing your addresses in both your database and a SOAP server?

Comment: I'm fetching and saving the SOAP response to the Rails database, so that the application doesn't have to make as many requests to the SOAP server, which is slowing down the app. @user.addresses would access all local addresses in the database. @user.addresses.fetch_from_soap would fetch new addresses and merge it with the database. I put the fetch_from_soap method as a class method inside address.rb. Maybe not the best place? I'd like to go to http://www.mysite.com/users/1/addresses/fetch_from_soap to call the fetch_from_soap method and pass the user_id as part of the SOAP request.

Comment: I see. First, calling @user.addresses.fetch_from_soap will *not* call any method in the Address class, either instance or class. @user.addresses returns an array of Addresses, but has nothing to do with the Address class itself. What you're accidentally doing is telling Ruby to look for an instance method called fetch_from_soap in the Array class, which of course won't exist, and shouldn't. (Continued...)

Comment: What you probably mean to do is something like this - Address.fetch_from_soap(@user). Have that class method grab the SOAP records for the user you pass in. Then take those results, loop through them, and save them to your database as Address records.

Comment: And if you don't like the look of Address.fetch_from_soap(@user), then wrap it inside a User instance method, perhaps one called fetch_addresses_from_soap. That method would call Address.fetch_from_soap(self). Then in your Controller (or wherever), you could just call @user.fetch_addresses_from_soap, which is arguably prettier.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did a test, and it looks like I was able to access class methods within the Address class via `@user.addresses.fetch_from_soap(@user)` by putting `def self.fetch_from_soap` inside address.rb. You're right that I could just do Address.fetch_from_soap(@user) as well.